# ASP.net mvc How to handle 404 which caused by missing of file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, download, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have file in folder "/UploadDir/TextFile1.txt"
I need:

1. download file if it exists
2. if file not exists (for example url :"/UploadDir/TextFile2.txt") should be shown custom errors message.

But now my mvc application not handle any requests to missed or existing files, when i place breackpoint on Application_BeginRequest and try to request text file - nothing occurred.

Besides i tryed to override HttpNotFound and HandleUnknownAction but same unsuccessfully.

Who can help me how to hande request to file if it exists or show custom error if it not found.

ps. route configuration is default

Comment: What is the value of runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the request `GET /UploadDir/TextFile1.txt` is being handled by IIS and not being passed into the ASP.NET pipeline. IIS will attempt to serve the content using its static file handler due to the `.txt` extension, and discover the file does not exist, issuing a 404.

You need to change your configuration to make these requests be passed to the ASP.NET handler for further processing. The exact details of that depend on your version of IIS.

Comment: I have latest iis 7.5 version, can you provide me any example for handling file.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough on IIS7 to give you exact steps - I'd have to play around with an IIS7 instance to work it out and I don't have one to hand. You might get better luck asking how to do this over on http://ServerFault.com.